# WPF application to Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I have been given a Windows Presentation Foundation application that uses a SQL Compact database and runs as a standalone on the users p.c. It is pretty good...It scans card numbers.

The business people have asked me for a solution to the following.
1) Take the current WPF application and make it run on the web

2) But if some of the customers have no internet access have a single solution that will meet the needs of intenet and non internet connected customers. I am an oracle dba! So in the dark but my suggestions are

1) Start from scratch with an ASP.net web application and SQL Server database for all the internet connected customers.Can we scan a card number to an ASP.net application?

2) For those who are not connected just let them keep the standalone application.But There was a suggestion that I should have a single software solution..grr! That would mean the ASP.net solution could also be installed locally for the none-internet customers...I thought this was not a good idea as the install would be like a mini webserver,database,and asp.net application all on a local pc.

So please some advice on the best software solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into xbap solutions. Assuming you have source codes for WPF app it should be easy to make a xbap app that runs on web browser.

You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx).